# Remove framework from Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having huge troubles removing a framework. It happens to be the WebRTC framework and I dragged it into the left hand side in Xcode, and added to the linked frameworks in the project target.

I now want to get rid of this framework.

Removing from the Linked Frameworks and libraries sections gives an error (device only):

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC

If I delete the framework manually from the project the compiler displays errors including use of undeclared type UILabel.

I haven't been using swift long - has anyone got any guidance on how to just remove this framework from my project.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this..
select **project target** > **build Phase** > **Link Binary With Libraries**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there is only my pods listed there; I've already removed WebRTC